# Create JSON from select element

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a web page that lists information for students in my database.  One of the fields is their birth country.  Currently, the database has stored the full name of the country they were born in.  I need to convert those full country names to a two-character string.  For example, "United States" will become 'US', and "Mexico" will become 'MX'.

There is a another web page on my server that contains a select element that has a list of all these countries, but it stores values as the two-character code I need for the other field.

I want to use this select element essentially as a lookup to determine what the proper two-character code should be given the country name on the first page.

Here's the code for one of my data rows:

```
<tr id="38768">
    <td style="width:25px" class="">&nbsp</td>
    <td align="right">17</td>
    <td style="background-image: none !important;">LastName, FirstName</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="17-ereg_hls_date" value="08/03/2015" readonly></td>  
    <td><input type="text" id="17-ereg_hlid" value="1" readonly></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="17-ereg_bc" value="Mexico" readonly></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="17-sri_hls_date" value="" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="17-sri_hlid" value="99" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="17-sri_bc" value="" /></td>
</tr>
```

I've found that I can pull in the select element from the other page using something like:

```
$j("#test").load("/admin/students/state/usa_ia/stateIA_BirthCountry.html [name*='Birth_Country']");
```

The element is coded as:

```
<select name="[Students.S_IA_STU_X]Birth_Country">
    <option value="AF">Afghanistan
    <option value="AX">Åland Islands
    <option value="AL">Albania
    ...
    <option value="ZW">Zimbabwe
</select>
```

I *think* what I want to do is load the information from the select element into a JSON object or js array, and then do my lookup from there.

How can I take this select element and create a key/value object of some kind?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just create a new DDL like:

```
<select name="country">
<option value="">Country...</option>
<option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
<option value="AL">Albania</option>
<option value="DZ">Algeria</option>
<option value="AS">American Samoa</option>
<option value="AD">Andorra</option>
<option value="AG">Angola</option>
<option value="AI">Anguilla</option>
<option value="AG">Antigua &amp; Barbuda</option>
<option value="AR">Argentina</option>
<option value="AA">Armenia</option>
<option value="AW">Aruba</option>
<option value="AU">Australia</option>
<option value="AT">Austria</option>
<option value="AZ">Azerbaijan</option>
<option value="BS">Bahamas</option>
<option value="BH">Bahrain</option>
<option value="BD">Bangladesh</option>
<option value="BB">Barbados</option>
<option value="BY">Belarus</option>
<option value="BE">Belgium</option>
<option value="BZ">Belize</option>
<option value="BJ">Benin</option>
<option value="BM">Bermuda</option>
<option value="BT">Bhutan</option>
<option value="BO">Bolivia</option>
<option value="BL">Bonaire</option>
<option value="BA">Bosnia &amp; Herzegovina</option>
<option value="BW">Botswana</option>
<option value="BR">Brazil</option>
<option value="BC">British Indian Ocean Ter</option>
<option value="BN">Brunei</option>
<option value="BG">Bulgaria</option>
<option value="BF">Burkina Faso</option>
<option value="BI">Burundi</option>
<option value="KH">Cambodia</option>
<option value="CM">Cameroon</option>
<option value="CA">Canada</option>
<option value="IC">Canary Islands</option>
<option value="CV">Cape Verde</option>
<option value="KY">Cayman Islands</option>
<option value="CF">Central African Republic</option>
<option value="TD">Chad</option>
<option value="CD">Channel Islands</option>
<option value="CL">Chile</option>
<option value="CN">China</option>
<option value="CI">Christmas Island</option>
<option value="CS">Cocos Island</option>
<option value="CO">Colombia</option>
<option value="CC">Comoros</option>
<option value="CG">Congo</option>
<option value="CK">Cook Islands</option>
<option value="CR">Costa Rica</option>
<option value="CT">Cote D'Ivoire</option>
<option value="HR">Croatia</option>
<option value="CU">Cuba</option>
<option value="CB">Curacao</option>
<option value="CY">Cyprus</option>
<option value="CZ">Czech Republic</option>
<option value="DK">Denmark</option>
<option value="DJ">Djibouti</option>
<option value="DM">Dominica</option>
<option value="DO">Dominican Republic</option>
<option value="TM">East Timor</option>
<option value="EC">Ecuador</option>
<option value="EG">Egypt</option>
<option value="SV">El Salvador</option>
<option value="GQ">Equatorial Guinea</option>
<option value="ER">Eritrea</option>
<option value="EE">Estonia</option>
<option value="ET">Ethiopia</option>
<option value="FA">Falkland Islands</option>
<option value="FO">Faroe Islands</option>
<option value="FJ">Fiji</option>
<option value="FI">Finland</option>
<option value="FR">France</option>
<option value="GF">French Guiana</option>
<option value="PF">French Polynesia</option>
<option value="FS">French Southern Ter</option>
<option value="GA">Gabon</option>
<option value="GM">Gambia</option>
<option value="GE">Georgia</option>
<option value="DE">Germany</option>
<option value="GH">Ghana</option>
<option value="GI">Gibraltar</option>
<option value="GB">Great Britain</option>
<option value="GR">Greece</option>
<option value="GL">Greenland</option>
<option value="GD">Grenada</option>
<option value="GP">Guadeloupe</option>
<option value="GU">Guam</option>
<option value="GT">Guatemala</option>
<option value="GN">Guinea</option>
<option value="GY">Guyana</option>
<option value="HT">Haiti</option>
<option value="HW">Hawaii</option>
<option value="HN">Honduras</option>
<option value="HK">Hong Kong</option>
<option value="HU">Hungary</option>
<option value="IS">Iceland</option>
<option value="IN">India</option>
<option value="ID">Indonesia</option>
<option value="IA">Iran</option>
<option value="IQ">Iraq</option>
<option value="IR">Ireland</option>
<option value="IM">Isle of Man</option>
<option value="IL">Israel</option>
<option value="IT">Italy</option>
<option value="JM">Jamaica</option>
<option value="JP">Japan</option>
<option value="JO">Jordan</option>
<option value="KZ">Kazakhstan</option>
<option value="KE">Kenya</option>
<option value="KI">Kiribati</option>
<option value="NK">Korea North</option>
<option value="KS">Korea South</option>
<option value="KW">Kuwait</option>
<option value="KG">Kyrgyzstan</option>
<option value="LA">Laos</option>
<option value="LV">Latvia</option>
<option value="LB">Lebanon</option>
<option value="LS">Lesotho</option>
<option value="LR">Liberia</option>
<option value="LY">Libya</option>
<option value="LI">Liechtenstein</option>
<option value="LT">Lithuania</option>
<option value="LU">Luxembourg</option>
<option value="MO">Macau</option>
<option value="MK">Macedonia</option>
<option value="MG">Madagascar</option>
<option value="MY">Malaysia</option>
<option value="MW">Malawi</option>
<option value="MV">Maldives</option>
<option value="ML">Mali</option>
<option value="MT">Malta</option>
<option value="MH">Marshall Islands</option>
<option value="MQ">Martinique</option>
<option value="MR">Mauritania</option>
<option value="MU">Mauritius</option>
<option value="ME">Mayotte</option>
<option value="MX">Mexico</option>
<option value="MI">Midway Islands</option>
<option value="MD">Moldova</option>
<option value="MC">Monaco</option>
<option value="MN">Mongolia</option>
<option value="MS">Montserrat</option>
<option value="MA">Morocco</option>
<option value="MZ">Mozambique</option>
<option value="MM">Myanmar</option>
<option value="NA">Nambia</option>
<option value="NU">Nauru</option>
<option value="NP">Nepal</option>
<option value="AN">Netherland Antilles</option>
<option value="NL">Netherlands (Holland, Europe)</option>
<option value="NV">Nevis</option>
<option value="NC">New Caledonia</option>
<option value="NZ">New Zealand</option>
<option value="NI">Nicaragua</option>
<option value="NE">Niger</option>
<option value="NG">Nigeria</option>
<option value="NW">Niue</option>
<option value="NF">Norfolk Island</option>
<option value="NO">Norway</option>
<option value="OM">Oman</option>
<option value="PK">Pakistan</option>
<option value="PW">Palau Island</option>
<option value="PS">Palestine</option>
<option value="PA">Panama</option>
<option value="PG">Papua New Guinea</option>
<option value="PY">Paraguay</option>
<option value="PE">Peru</option>
<option value="PH">Philippines</option>
<option value="PO">Pitcairn Island</option>
<option value="PL">Poland</option>
<option value="PT">Portugal</option>
<option value="PR">Puerto Rico</option>
<option value="QA">Qatar</option>
<option value="ME">Republic of Montenegro</option>
<option value="RS">Republic of Serbia</option>
<option value="RE">Reunion</option>
<option value="RO">Romania</option>
<option value="RU">Russia</option>
<option value="RW">Rwanda</option>
<option value="NT">St Barthelemy</option>
<option value="EU">St Eustatius</option>
<option value="HE">St Helena</option>
<option value="KN">St Kitts-Nevis</option>
<option value="LC">St Lucia</option>
<option value="MB">St Maarten</option>
<option value="PM">St Pierre &amp; Miquelon</option>
<option value="VC">St Vincent &amp; Grenadines</option>
<option value="SP">Saipan</option>
<option value="SO">Samoa</option>
<option value="AS">Samoa American</option>
<option value="SM">San Marino</option>
<option value="ST">Sao Tome &amp; Principe</option>
<option value="SA">Saudi Arabia</option>
<option value="SN">Senegal</option>
<option value="RS">Serbia</option>
<option value="SC">Seychelles</option>
<option value="SL">Sierra Leone</option>
<option value="SG">Singapore</option>
<option value="SK">Slovakia</option>
<option value="SI">Slovenia</option>
<option value="SB">Solomon Islands</option>
<option value="OI">Somalia</option>
<option value="ZA">South Africa</option>
<option value="ES">Spain</option>
<option value="LK">Sri Lanka</option>
<option value="SD">Sudan</option>
<option value="SR">Suriname</option>
<option value="SZ">Swaziland</option>
<option value="SE">Sweden</option>
<option value="CH">Switzerland</option>
<option value="SY">Syria</option>
<option value="TA">Tahiti</option>
<option value="TW">Taiwan</option>
<option value="TJ">Tajikistan</option>
<option value="TZ">Tanzania</option>
<option value="TH">Thailand</option>
<option value="TG">Togo</option>
<option value="TK">Tokelau</option>
<option value="TO">Tonga</option>
<option value="TT">Trinidad &amp; Tobago</option>
<option value="TN">Tunisia</option>
<option value="TR">Turkey</option>
<option value="TU">Turkmenistan</option>
<option value="TC">Turks &amp; Caicos Is</option>
<option value="TV">Tuvalu</option>
<option value="UG">Uganda</option>
<option value="UA">Ukraine</option>
<option value="AE">United Arab Emirates</option>
<option value="GB">United Kingdom</option>
<option value="US">United States of America</option>
<option value="UY">Uruguay</option>
<option value="UZ">Uzbekistan</option>
<option value="VU">Vanuatu</option>
<option value="VS">Vatican City State</option>
<option value="VE">Venezuela</option>
<option value="VN">Vietnam</option>
<option value="VB">Virgin Islands (Brit)</option>
<option value="VA">Virgin Islands (USA)</option>
<option value="WK">Wake Island</option>
<option value="WF">Wallis &amp; Futana Is</option>
<option value="YE">Yemen</option>
<option value="ZR">Zaire</option>
<option value="ZM">Zambia</option>
<option value="ZW">Zimbabwe</option>
</select>
```

Comment: In the options presented in the post have an `AX`

Comment: Well then I suggested adding: <option value="AX">Åland Islands between Afghanistan and Albania options.

Comment: Not an option. The page that is storing the full country names comes from the company that creates the product riding on top of the database.  To modify their page would both break their internal coding, and my usage agreement with them.  Therefore, I need to write outside of the pages that come with the product.

Answer (score 1):

Just use an object like this:

```
var iso3166 = {
    'Afghanistan': 'AF',
    'Albania': 'AL',
    'Algeria': 'DZ',
    'American Samoa': 'AS',
    'Andorra': 'AD',
    'Angola': 'AG',
    'Anguilla': 'AI',
    'Antigua & Barbuda': 'AG',
    'Argentina': 'AR',
    'Armenia': 'AA',
    'Aruba': 'AW',
    'Australia': 'AU',
    'Austria': 'AT',
    'Azerbaijan': 'AZ',
    'Bahamas': 'BS',
    'Bahrain': 'BH',
    'Bangladesh': 'BD',
    'Barbados': 'BB',
    'Belarus': 'BY',
    'Belgium': 'BE',
    'Belize': 'BZ',
    'Benin': 'BJ',
    'Bermuda': 'BM',
    'Bhutan': 'BT',
    'Bolivia': 'BO',
    'Bonaire': 'BL',
    'Bosnia & Herzegovina': 'BA',
    'Botswana': 'BW',
    'Brazil': 'BR',
    'British Indian Ocean Ter': 'BC',
    'Brunei': 'BN',
    'Bulgaria': 'BG',
    'Burkina Faso': 'BF',
    'Burundi': 'BI',
    'Cambodia': 'KH',
    'Cameroon': 'CM',
    'Canada': 'CA',
    'Canary Islands': 'IC',
    'Cape Verde': 'CV',
    'Cayman Islands': 'KY',
    'Central African Republic': 'CF',
    'Chad': 'TD',
    'Channel Islands': 'CD',
    'Chile': 'CL',
    'China': 'CN',
    'Christmas Island': 'CI',
    'Cocos Island': 'CS',
    'Colombia': 'CO',
    'Comoros': 'CC',
    'Congo': 'CG',
    'Cook Islands': 'CK',
    'Costa Rica': 'CR',
    'Cote D`\'Ivoire': 'CT',
    'Croatia': 'HR',
    'Cuba': 'CU',
    'Curacao': 'CB',
    'Cyprus': 'CY',
    'Czech Republic': 'CZ',
    'Denmark': 'DK',
    'Djibouti': 'DJ',
    'Dominica': 'DM',
    'Dominican Republic': 'DO',
    'East Timor': 'TM',
    'Ecuador': 'EC',
    'Egypt': 'EG',
    'El Salvador': 'SV',
    'Equatorial Guinea': 'GQ',
    'Eritrea': 'ER',
    'Estonia': 'EE',
    'Ethiopia': 'ET',
    'Falkland Islands': 'FA',
    'Faroe Islands': 'FO',
    'Fiji': 'FJ',
    'Finland': 'FI',
    'France': 'FR',
    'French Guiana': 'GF',
    'French Polynesia': 'PF',
    'French Southern Ter': 'FS',
    'Gabon': 'GA',
    'Gambia': 'GM',
    'Georgia': 'GE',
    'Germany': 'DE',
    'Ghana': 'GH',
    'Gibraltar': 'GI',
    'Great Britain': 'GB',
    'Greece': 'GR',
    'Greenland': 'GL',
    'Grenada': 'GD',
    'Guadeloupe': 'GP',
    'Guam': 'GU',
    'Guatemala': 'GT',
    'Guinea': 'GN',
    'Guyana': 'GY',
    'Haiti': 'HT',
    'Hawaii': 'HW',
    'Honduras': 'HN',
    'Hong Kong': 'HK',
    'Hungary': 'HU',
    'Iceland': 'IS',
    'India': 'IN',
    'Indonesia': 'ID',
    'Iran': 'IA',
    'Iraq': 'IQ',
    'Ireland': 'IR',
    'Isle of Man': 'IM',
    'Israel': 'IL',
    'Italy': 'IT',
    'Jamaica': 'JM',
    'Japan': 'JP',
    'Jordan': 'JO',
    'Kazakhstan': 'KZ',
    'Kenya': 'KE',
    'Kiribati': 'KI',
    'Korea North': 'NK',
    'Korea South': 'KS',
    'Kuwait': 'KW',
    'Kyrgyzstan': 'KG',
    'Laos': 'LA',
    'Latvia': 'LV',
    'Lebanon': 'LB',
    'Lesotho': 'LS',
    'Liberia': 'LR',
    'Libya': 'LY',
    'Liechtenstein': 'LI',
    'Lithuania': 'LT',
    'Luxembourg': 'LU',
    'Macau': 'MO',
    'Macedonia': 'MK',
    'Madagascar': 'MG',
    'Malaysia': 'MY',
    'Malawi': 'MW',
    'Maldives': 'MV',
    'Mali': 'ML',
    'Malta': 'MT',
    'Marshall Islands': 'MH',
    'Martinique': 'MQ',
    'Mauritania': 'MR',
    'Mauritius': 'MU',
    'Mayotte': 'ME',
    'Mexico': 'MX',
    'Midway Islands': 'MI',
    'Moldova': 'MD',
    'Monaco': 'MC',
    'Mongolia': 'MN',
    'Montserrat': 'MS',
    'Morocco': 'MA',
    'Mozambique': 'MZ',
    'Myanmar': 'MM',
    'Nambia': 'NA',
    'Nauru': 'NU',
    'Nepal': 'NP',
    'Netherland Antilles': 'AN',
    'Netherlands (Holland, Europe)': 'NL',
    'Nevis': 'NV',
    'New Caledonia': 'NC',
    'New Zealand': 'NZ',
    'Nicaragua': 'NI',
    'Niger': 'NE',
    'Nigeria': 'NG',
    'Niue': 'NW',
    'Norfolk Island': 'NF',
    'Norway': 'NO',
    'Oman': 'OM',
    'Pakistan': 'PK',
    'Palau Island': 'PW',
    'Palestine': 'PS',
    'Panama': 'PA',
    'Papua New Guinea': 'PG',
    'Paraguay': 'PY',
    'Peru': 'PE',
    'Philippines': 'PH',
    'Pitcairn Island': 'PO',
    'Poland': 'PL',
    'Portugal': 'PT',
    'Puerto Rico': 'PR',
    'Qatar': 'QA',
    'Republic of Montenegro': 'ME',
    'Republic of Serbia': 'RS',
    'Reunion': 'RE',
    'Romania': 'RO',
    'Russia': 'RU',
    'Rwanda': 'RW',
    'St Barthelemy': 'NT',
    'St Eustatius': 'EU',
    'St Helena': 'HE',
    'St Kitts-Nevis': 'KN',
    'St Lucia': 'LC',
    'St Maarten': 'MB',
    'St Pierre & Miquelon': 'PM',
    'St Vincent & Grenadines': 'VC',
    'Saipan': 'SP',
    'Samoa': 'SO',
    'Samoa American': 'AS',
    'San Marino': 'SM',
    'Sao Tome & Principe': 'ST',
    'Saudi Arabia': 'SA',
    'Senegal': 'SN',
    'Serbia': 'RS',
    'Seychelles': 'SC',
    'Sierra Leone': 'SL',
    'Singapore': 'SG',
    'Slovakia': 'SK',
    'Slovenia': 'SI',
    'Solomon Islands': 'SB',
    'Somalia': 'OI',
    'South Africa': 'ZA',
    'Spain': 'ES',
    'Sri Lanka': 'LK',
    'Sudan': 'SD',
    'Suriname': 'SR',
    'Swaziland': 'SZ',
    'Sweden': 'SE',
    'Switzerland': 'CH',
    'Syria': 'SY',
    'Tahiti': 'TA',
    'Taiwan': 'TW',
    'Tajikistan': 'TJ',
    'Tanzania': 'TZ',
    'Thailand': 'TH',
    'Togo': 'TG',
    'Tokelau': 'TK',
    'Tonga': 'TO',
    'Trinidad & Tobago': 'TT',
    'Tunisia': 'TN',
    'Turkey': 'TR',
    'Turkmenistan': 'TU',
    'Turks & Caicos Is': 'TC',
    'Tuvalu': 'TV',
    'Uganda': 'UG',
    'Ukraine': 'UA',
    'United Arab Emirates': 'AE',
    'United Kingdom': 'GB',
    'United States of America': 'US',
    'Uruguay': 'UY',
    'Uzbekistan': 'UZ',
    'Vanuatu': 'VU',
    'Vatican City State': 'VS',
    'Venezuela': 'VE',
    'Vietnam': 'VN',
    'Virgin Islands (Brit)': 'VB',
    'Virgin Islands (USA)': 'VA',
    'Wake Island': 'WK',
    'Wallis & Futana Is': 'WF',
    'Yemen': 'YE',
    'Zaire': 'ZR',
    'Zambia': 'ZM',
    'Zimbabwe': 'ZW'
};
```

Comment: Where's the fun in that?  :-)  Honestly, this may be the most practical solution, as long as defining these manually line up with what is coded back in that other element, and the company doesn't modify them in the future.  TY :-)

Comment: the problem, you are describing, is not so trivial as it look like, because you have the data and if the data is consistent, you can decide how to convert the given data to the iso3166 code.

Answer (score 0):

This answer requires jQuery.

Once you've loaded the element, just find the child options and store the info you need in an object.

```
var nameToCode = {};

$(...).find('option').each(function () {
    nameToCode[$(this).text()] = $(this).val();
});
```

Then you could just change the data using a query to update all of the elements.

```
$('[id$=ereg_bc]').each(function () {
    $(this).val(nameToCode[$(this).val()]);
});
```